# A single line way to populate a map from a list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm porting the equivalent of this code from Python 2.x to Python 3.x

```
def funk(arg):
    return "%s" % str(arg)

args = map(funk, [1, 2, 3, 4])
args += [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The last line as of Python 3 gives the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'map' and 'list'
```

How can I replace the last line with a single line of code?

Comment: `args = list(map(funk, [1, 2, 3, 4]))`. `map` return an iterator in Python 3, not a simple list. If you want a list, you must explicitly cast the iterator to one via `list(...)`.

Comment: @ChristianDean This is a boiled-down example.  In the actual example I can't easily make the args a list.

Comment: Well I'm afraid you're going to have to. You can't in-place add an iterator and a list. It just won't work. I don't see why you can't however, care to to elaborate?

Comment: @empty In python 2 map returns a list so how does the code work if args can't be a list? If it really can't be a list use itertools.chain.

Comment: `def funk(*args) : if len_your_args > 1 : map_this; else : save_your_data_to_somewhere`

Answer (score 2):

The return value for `map` has changed in Python 3, it now returns an iterator for values like `itertools.imap` does in Python 2. You will need to apply `list` to the output of map to get a list now as Christian suggests. If you want your code to be portable across Python 2 and 3 you can use the `six` package to import a version of `map` which returns an iterator: `from six.moves import map`